# Regular expression to extract characters between a space and a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"Samsung LA32D450 LCD Television 32inch Black"
```

I need to extract the size of the TV so I need to extract all characters between 'inch' and the preceeding whitespace. In this case I would need the expression to return `32`

The regular expression needs to be able to deal with decimal points.
For example I would need `32.5` from this string:

```
"Samsung LA32D450 LCD Television 32.5inch Black"
```

Comment: Not all cases are 6 strings separated by spaces. I tried \d+(?=inch) but that doesn't deal with the cases where there are decimal points in the TV size e.g. it returns just 5 in the second example

Comment: Please add as many examples as you can, and please check if this solves your problem : https://regex101.com/r/xCZjlr/4

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it useful, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match numbers (possibly including a dot) followed by the word `inch`.

You can use [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get what you want:

```
[\d.]+(?=inch)
```

This will match a combination of numbers an dots repeated 1 or more times followed by the word `inch`.

You can of course, get more precise by specifying the format of the numbers.

**EDIT**:

Getting more precise about the number format can introduce extra complexities. I came up with this regex to match only either 2-3 digits followed by "inch" (`23inch`) or just 2-3 digits followed by a dot followed by one digit followed by "inch"(`23.5inch`). It uses both lookaheads and negative lookbehinds so your regex engine should support these constructs:

```
\b(?<![.\d])([1-9][0-9]{1,2}\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2})(?=inch)
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/xCZjlr/11)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
library(stringr)
a <- "Samsung LA32D450 LCD Television 32.1inch Black"
str_extract(a, "[:graph:]*(?=inch)")
```

[:graph:] matches either letters, numbers or punctuation, but not white-space.

?=inch matches everything followed by "inch".

Good luck,

Ludo

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\s)(\d+\.?\d*)(?=inch)
```

It matches the part that comes before `inch`. `\d+` part matches decimal part and then it matches for an optional `.`. After that it looks for fractional part with `\d*`.

After realizing that it accepts numbers like `.6`, I make a quick edit. It looks for space character before digit part.

https://regex101.com/r/tionn9/2